# Fix for Cognitive Complexity for multiple if else conditions in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

This is my code which is working fine. But when I push the code, the sonarqube quality gate fails due to  Cognitive Complexity. Any ideas on fixing this sonar issue

```
if (bbResponse.getEmails() != null && !bbResponse.getEmails().isEmpty()) {

        bbResponse.getEmails().stream().forEach((BBEmail bbEmail) -> {
            if ("CHK".equals(bbEmail.getSEQ())) {
                //CODE
            } else if ("CHT".equals(bbEmail.getSEQ())) {
                //CODE
            } else if ("MYT".equals(bbEmail.getSEQ())) {
                //CODE
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You could also do this with a `switch` statement (unless you are using a super-old version of Java). But I don't know if Sonarqube will see that as less complex.

Comment: Simplify it further. hmm.. Try declaring identifiers for these: `bbResponse.getEmails()` and `bbEmail.getSEQ()`

Comment: Check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-replace-if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas (don't know whether they satisfy Sonarqube):

- The test `bbResponse.getEmails().isEmpty()` isn't necessary. `forEach()` on an empty list is perfectly valid, will execute its    body zero times.
- As written in comments already, you can replace the string comparison conditionals by a switch statement.
- You can refactor the lambda expression into a method of its own and use a method reference in the `forEach()` call.
- You can refactor the blocks given as `//CODE` in your post, into methods of their own, if they are longer than a handful of lines.

By the way:

While Sonarqube surely gives valuable advice, I'd never make it a hard quality gate.

Having an automat with somewhat obscure rules decide on acceptable code style doesn't seem like a good idea to me. We all want clean, human-readable code, and that's not the same as Sonarqube-compatible code.

E.g. Sonarqube isn't able to judge the most important aspect of readability: the naming of classes, fields, variables and so on. And your issue shows that e.g. the complexity rule rejects code that no developer would ever judge as "difficult to read" (unless the "CODE" blocks that you omitted are overly long).

Answer (score 0):

1. A check for non empty list may be redundant if you use `stream()`, _as well as `forEach` may be used without calling `.stream()`
2. It is possible to prepare a map of consumer methods for specific codes
3. Use `Optional::ifPresentOrElse` when getting a nullable consumer from the map or throw an exception.

```java
static void handleEmails(List<BBEmail> emails) {

    if (null != emails) {
        Map<String, Consumer<BBEmail>> codes = Map.of(
                "CHK", MyClass::processChkEmail,
                "CHT", MyClass::processChtEmail,
                "MYT", MyClass::processMytEmail
        );
        emails.orEach(bbEmail -> 
                  Optional.ofNullable(codes.get(bbEmail.getSEQ()))
                          .ifPresentOrElse(consumer -> consumer.accept(bbEmail),
                                           () -> {throw new IllegalStateException();}
                          )
              );
    }
}

static void processChkEmail(BBEmail email) {
    // TODO CHK
}

static void processChtEmail(BBEmail email) {
    // TODO CHT
}

static void processMytEmail(BBEmail email) {
    // TODO MYT
}
```

This should resolve Sonar issue but I am not quite sure it increases readability for humans :)

---

Another previously mentioned option is `switch` statement -- which can be even more concise for Java 12+ syntax without `break` statements:

```java
static void handleEmailSwitchJava12(List<BBEmail> emails) {
    if (null != emails) {
        emails.forEach(bbEmail -> {
            switch (bbEmail.getSEQ()) {
                case "CHK" -> processChkEmail(bbEmail);
                case "CHT" -> processChtEmail(bbEmail); 
                case "MYT" -> processMytEmail(bbEmail);
                default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid SEQ code: " + bbEmail.getSEQ());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. But defintely it will make more complex to read :)

Comment: @Syed, `switch` version is fairly more readable.  However, if you get rid of `isEmpty` check and using straight `emails.forEach` it should decrease "complexity" and satisfy Sonar :)